# How to get the value of the dropdown list in kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid with dropdown and a checkbox. When ever i have checked the checkbox i want to get the value of the drop downlist that is selected. How can i do that using kendoui

Comment: How did you define define the `dropdown` and the `checkbox`. Did you use some KendoUI template? Could you show some code on how did you define the columns of your grid?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
var $checkBox = $("#myCheckbox");
$checkBox.click(function () {
    if ($checkBox.is(':checked')) {
        var $dropDownVal = $('#myDropdownBox').val();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it is that easy since the both `dropdown` and `checkbox` are in a Kendo UI `grid` and I don't know if @Avinash knows the `id`s.